# Socket write error while using ObjectOutputStream's writeObject method

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, client-server

I am trying to implement FTP protocol using socket programing in java. I am using the ObjectOutputStream to write the data requested to the socket in the server side but i am getting the following error on the console window..

> Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Here is the implementation of my program
Server side:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class FTPServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(4550);
            while(true) {
                Socket socket = ss.accept();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                FileInstance file = new FileInstance();

                System.out.println(file.srcDir = br.readLine());
                System.out.println(file.destDir = br.readLine());
                System.out.println(file.filename = file.srcDir.substring(file.srcDir.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));

                File f = new File(file.srcDir);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                fis.read(bytes);
                file.FILE_SIZE = bytes.length;
                file.fileData = bytes;

                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject(file);
                System.out.println("Success");
                oos.close();
                fis.close();
                br.close();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Client Side:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;


public class FTPClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4550);
            BufferedReader sbr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            System.out.println("Enter the path of requested file");
            String path = sbr.readLine();
            System.out.println(path);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            System.out.println("Enter Destination");
            path = path + "\n" + sbr.readLine();
            System.out.println(path);
            pw.write(path);
            pw.close();
            sbr.close();

            // receive file
            ObjectInputStream ois= new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            FileInstance file = (FileInstance)ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            if(!new File(file.destDir).exists())
                new File(file.destDir).mkdir();
            File nfile = new File(file.destDir + "/" + file.filename);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(nfile);
            fos.write(file.fileData);
            fos.close();
            socket.close();
            System.out.println("Success");

        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

this is the FileInstance class......

```
 import java.io.Serializable;

   public class FileInstance implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public String destDir;
        public String srcDir;
    public String filename;
    public long FILE_SIZE;
    public byte[] fileData;
    public String status; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this in a debugger yet? If not, start there.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have no experience of working with the debugger, i tried it though but the debugger passes through the breakpoint set on the creation of the ObjectOutputStream object and the call to the writeObject method without any error. please help

Comment: @JimGarrison i haven't been able to find the problem please give me atleast a hint.

Comment: Your code is not complete enough for anyone to debug it.  What is `FileInstance`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in `FTPClient`

1. You are closing the socket prematurely.  At line 22 `pw.close()` needs to be `pw.flush()`
2. Even after you fix the first issue the server will hang.  You need to add a newline to the end of the `path` string you send so the server, using `readLine()`, can read entire lines; otherwise it waits forever for a complete line that never arrives.

This was trivial to debug in Eclipse. If you want to be a good developer, debugging skills are crucial. Set more than one breakpoint and see what happens.  Experiment. Play.  Learn.